# React components only setting state for one key in constructor function. ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this component, but it's not setting show in the the state constructor. I can console.log the props and they show the correct params, but for some reason, show is not getting set.

```
class SubstitutionPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      suggestions: this.props.synonyms_with_levels,
      show: this.props.show
    } 
  }

  handleToggleShow() {
    this.setState({
      show: false
    })
  }


  render() {
    console.log("sub panel")
    console.log(this.state)
    console.log(this.props)
    if (this.props.synonyms_with_levels.length > 0 && this.state.show) {
      return(
        <div className="substitution-panel">
          <div onClick={() => this.handleToggleShow()} className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove hover-hand"></div>
          {this.props.synonyms_with_levels}
        </div>
      );      
    } else {
      return (
        <span>
        </span>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The parent that renders this child component looks like this:

```
<SubstitutionPanel synonyms_with_levels=    {this.props.synonyms_with_levels} show={this.state.showSubPane} />
```

I'm really just trying to make a "tooltip" where the parent can open the tooltip.

Comment: Are you saying `this.state.show` is not showing the correct value when you console.log it in the constructor even though `this.props.show` is showing the correct value? Or that your `setState` call isn't functioning properly?

Comment: this.state.show  is still showing as false even if I pass it as true in the parent. The constructor function is setting suggestions, but cannot set "show."

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me: https://jsbin.com/xocebaduwa/edit?js,output Are you sure `synonyms_with_levels` is not zero length?

Answer (score 0):

Is everything ok when you console.log(this.props)?

It may be just a typo here, but in the parent component you have

```
show={this.state.showSubPane}
```

and maybe it should be 'showSubPanel' with an L at the end?